Typo3 Frontend Performance Issues - Slow Page Loading
For many years, our website, which was built using Typo3, has been experiencing slow performance for the past week.
When we try to visit our site, the loading times are quite slow, sometimes taking 3-4 seconds, while other times it can take up to 1 minute.
There are no performance issues on the backend side; it works properly and quickly as before.
No changes have been made to our website in the last 1-2 months. No new posts were added, no plugins were installed, yet suddenly the page loading became very slow, even though nothing was done.
Here are the topics I have researched so far to find a solution:

Since we host our website on our own server, there is sufficient disk space, CPU, and RAM available. This has been checked.
All log files were checked, and no problems or error reports were found.
3.No new plugins were added, removed, or updated. In other words, no changes were made.
Errors and warnings in the php.ini file in the install tools section of the website were corrected. Only the PHP SOAP and ZIP extensions could not be loaded and activated due to our server being old, and we cannot install packages.
Using the Typo3 Install Tool interface, everything like Database Analyzer, Clear all cache, Check for broken extensions were checked and run, but we still did not see any errors or improvements.

Our website is hosted on a server running Debian 9.8.0, with 8 vCPUs, 20 GB RAM, and 1 TB disk space.
The Typo3 version we are using is Typo3 v6.2.26.
So far, we have not been able to find a solution in our research as to why this problem suddenly appeared and how we can fix it.
Thank you in advance for your help and suggestions.

After v6.2.26 there have been at least 3 known security issues. Maybe, read through the issues and check if you have been hacked.
And, of course, you should update your TYPO3 to the latest available security-release-version

Thank you for the suggestions. I will check them and if there is a development, I will share the solution with you.

When was the last time you OPTIMIZE TABLE tbl_name?  Any table?  Year and month?

Could you post TEXT of one Query that is consistently slow?

Some more Ideas:

Maybe check https://pagespeed.web.dev/ to get an idea, if the server is the problem or TYPO3
Check if caching is activated in your TYPO3
Check browsers console + network analysis for error and problems (very big images, waiting times while loading, blocking / external scripts, blocking css...)
Check TYPO3 errorlog, maybe it´s very big. If so, delete it
Check if some tables grown big in your database (logs etc.)
Check if your website has been hacked
use the admin panel (not sure if existing in TYPO3 6.2..), to find bottlenecks etc.

And as said before: Update your TYPO3! Beside security issus newer TYPO3 Versions can use newer PHP Version, which could speed up your website too.

there were too many log files in the background, after deleting them from the database and cleaning the cookies in the install tool, the problem was solved thank you

If suddenly something becomes slow without changes then I would look onto the server. Maybe something takes resources from your webserver at that time?
Furthermore you have to find the bottleneck, typo3 does a lots of stuff when loading a page, generating CSS/JS assets, regenerate images via grphicsmagic and imagemagick, but all of these should be cached on the server once the page is loaded.
Is there a cleanup routine that automatically cleans the cache from your page? Because then the TYPO3 needs to regenerate all of this and the first contact will be slow.
Next are database queries, there are a lot so you can check if there is a bottleneck.
The php zip extension could be relevant, because typo3 has a setting to zip the assets for faster page speed.
Because of how old your version is, could there be an attack to your website and someone flooded your database?

Thank you for the suggestions. I will check them and if there is a development, I will share the solution with you.

I would suggest, that you first check the MySQL slow-queries log.
Should be at:
/var/log/mysql/slow-query.log
If the log is not activated here is how to do:
How do I enable the MySQL slow query log?
Maybe your sys_log table is over-filled. Especially long running TYPO3 systems, like yours seems to be, can have quite big log tables.
If the queries are not the problem, you could install XDebug on your server and do a profiling:
https://xdebug.org/docs/profiler
Not sure if the install instructions work for your system, if its also as outdated as your TYPO3 version.
Good luck.
